# df.to_csv is not generating a CSV file even with fully specified filepath

Tags: python, pandas

Still trying to learn Python. As a learning exercise, I tried to write a script to pull the last 5 years of historical bitcoin data from coinmarketcap.com. I have it so no errors are generated whatsoever, but no CSV file generates at the end. I read elsewhere it may save to another directory, but I can see the working directory is where I'm looking, and I used df.to_csv in another script in this directory and it saved correctly.

I am using Spyder through Anaconda Notebooks. Here is my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

coins = {}

for i in coins:
        page = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20150920&end=20200918')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        data = soup.find('script', id="__NEXT_DATA__",type="application/json")
        historical_data = json.loads(data.contents[0]) 
        quotes = historical_data['props']['initialState']['cryptocurrency']['ohlcvHistorical']['i']['quotes']

        market_cap = []
        volume = []
        timestamp = []
        name = []
        symbol = []
        slug = []
    
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['marketcap','volume','timestamp','name','symbol','slug'])
        for j in quotes:
            market_cap.append(j['quote']['USD']['market_cap'])
            volume.append(j['quote']['USD']['volume'])
            timestamp.append(j['quote']['USD']['timestamp'])
            name.append(info['name'])
            symbol.append(info['symbol'])
            slug.append(coins[i])
            df['marketcap'] = market_cap
            df['volume'] = volume
            df['timestamp'] = timestamp
            df['name'] = name
            df['symbol'] = symbol
            df['slug'] = slug
        df.to_csv('C:\\Python34\\Projects\\Trends\\btcvalue.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: `coins` is empty, so the loop will have 0 (zero) iterations and the code in it will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first for loop will never run, because `coins` is always empty. And I would suggest to move `df.to_csv` out of the for loop.

```
[...] 

coins = {}

for i in coins:

[...]

        df['slug'] = slug
df.to_csv('C:\\Python34\\Projects\\Trends\\btcvalue.csv', index=False)
```